# Getting the fully qualified URL for a local static file on a Windows LAN

Tags: windows, networking, filesystems, hyperlink

I am working on a corporate social bookmarking tool (for Windows users primarily). Users might bookmark local links with this tool, including those on network drives like:

```
//SERVER//something/file.doc
```

or something that is local, but still network-accessible (if the local settings allow)

```
//MYNAME_MYMACHINE/Desktop/file.doc
```

I want to make sure that when someone bookmarks a link like this:

```
c:/Desktop/file.doc
```

.. that I can actually determine what the C: reference is (since it could just be a mounted drive). In reality - this reference only makes sense for one person locally if they have mounted the drive under this letter locally. It will not work if someone else tries to click through to get to that resource.

My question is - how can I (using whatever means) - query a local file reference and resolve the fully qualified network path to any user-provided link? I wanted to extract the "most fully qualified version" of a link to maximise the chance that it will be clickable by someone else who is a member of the AD/LAN. This prevents the user having to worry about what "fully qualified" means for sharing a link to a fileshare, for example.

*Further - using this on the right-click menu in Windows*

The first part above determines the most fully-qualified network-accessible address for a resource. I then want to build a right-click button so that when somebody right-clicks a file in Windows Explorer - they see an option called *Bookmark & Share this File*. When they click that - the above resolution happens and the link to this file is saving on a server. The process this needs to go through is simple - it's a post to a JSON/XML endpoint for the app which saves the URL of the resource you want to save. How do I even begin doing this for various popular flavours of Windows? Is this called a "shell extension"?

Comment: For `c:/Desktop/file.doc`, would you be expecting `\\MYNAME_MYMACHINE\C$\Desktop\file.doc`? Resolving shares might add a level of difficulty here.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following resources:

1. [Get UNC path from a local path or mapped path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411606/get-unc-path-from-a-local-path-or-mapped-path)
2. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a45da6f3-aa74-46e2-8e7b-a54562cd2b5e